# Declaring array of voids

Tags: c, memory

I'm writing a program that copies files. I've used a buffer in order to store the information that the [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) function provides and then give this data to the [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) function. I've used this declaration:

```
static void buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

The problem is that I get the the error `error: declaration of ‘buffer’ as array of voids`.

I don't understand why declaring an array of void is an error. How can I declare a block of memory without a specific type?

Comment: Perhaps more to the point, what is the *size* of `void`?

Comment: One more Zen-ish question... please! :D

Comment: @JörgenSigvardsson: *is* a void at all?

Comment: Avoid a void since your allocation guarantees are void (:P).

Comment: A void, a void object!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I don't understand why declaring an array of void is an error.

The technical reason you cannot declare an array-of-`void` is that `void` is an **incomplete type that cannot be completed**. The size of array elements must be known but the void type has no size. Note that you are similarly unable to declare a void object, as in

```
void foo;
```

Note that a pointer-to-void has a specific size, which is why

```
void *foo;
```

is valid, as well as `sizeof(foo)`, but `sizeof(*foo)` would be invalid.

> How can I declare a block of memory without a specific type?

For generic memory buffers, use an array of plain `char` or `unsigned char` (or even `uint8_t`). I usually prefer plain `char` when I need to pass pointers to the `str*`  family of functions where array of `unsigned char` would lead to diagnostics about incompatible pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Use an array of `char` or `unsigned char` instead.

Comment: +1, I believe the OP is unaware that this is the ubiquitous `byte`-sized type in C given `void*` is the datatype requested by `read()` and `write()`.

Answer (score 2):

When declaring an array, the compiler must know the size of the array.
The void type has no size. So compiler report error.

Comment: More correct would be: the compiler has to know the size of the *element type*. The array size itself may be variable length.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it, although it is not an array of voids as you may have wanted, it is an array of void pointers; in each cell of this void pointer you can assign ANYTHING.

If you wish to store a variable, you simply cast it to (`void*`), here is an example:

```
void *XPoint[5] = { 0 };
XPoint[0] = (void*)5;   // int
XPoint[1] = "Olololo!"; // char*
XPoint[2] = (void*)'x'; // char
XPoint[3] = (void*)structA.nNum; // struct int
```

Answer (score -1):

You also can declare void pointer:

```
void* buffer;

// just pointers for simple work with allocated piece of memory
char* chBuf;
long* intBuf;
```

then use malloc() for this pointer and work with this piece of memory like with an any array (char, short, long, float, double or your own type). Don't forget to use free() to avoid memory leak in this case.

```
buffer = malloc (BUFFER_SIZE);
if (buffer==NULL)
  exit (1);

// init our buffers
chBuf=(*char)buffer;
intBuf=(*long)buffer;
```

Comment: Don't cast the output value of `malloc` in C.

Comment: That's in the C FAQ. Read it. Live it!

Comment: When you do `buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);` the return value of `malloc` is casted automatically to the type of buffer. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @chavaone No, it's not *casted* (which requires a cast operator). A `void` pointer in C is simply assignment-compatible to all pointer-to-object types.